# undefined behavior of HMAC-SHA512 giving different result each time

Tags: c, bitcoin, sha512

I wanted to derive a (44') hardened private key from the master key by applying HMAC(sha512,..), but I keep getting a different arbitrary result.
The strange thing is the same hmac-sha512 function was used the first time and gaves correct result by deriving the masterkey from the seed, but using it second time to get the hardned private key failed which i think it is something has to do with the memory as memcheck with valgrind showed several errors.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>


void GenerateMKey();
void CKDPrivate();


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    unsigned char seed[64]={0x67, 0xf9, 0x35, 0x60, 0x76, 0x1e, 0x20, 0x61, 0x7d, 0xe2,
                            0x6e, 0x0c, 0xb8, 0x4f, 0x72, 0x34, 0xaa, 0xf3, 0x73, 0xed,
                            0x2e, 0x66, 0x29, 0x5c, 0x3d, 0x73, 0x97, 0xe6, 0xd7, 0xeb,
                            0xe8, 0x82, 0xea, 0x39, 0x6d, 0x5d, 0x29, 0x38, 0x08, 0xb0,
                            0xde, 0xfd, 0x7e, 0xdd, 0x2b, 0xab, 0xd4, 0xc0, 0x91, 0xad,
                            0x94, 0x2e, 0x6a, 0x93, 0x51, 0xe6, 0xd0, 0x75, 0xa2, 0x9d,
                            0x4d, 0xf8, 0x72, 0xaf};
    unsigned char mkey[64];
    unsigned char ekey[64];
    //unsigned char n[4]={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    unsigned char h[4]={0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00};

    GenerateMKey(seed,mkey);
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){ printf("%02x",mkey[i]);} printf("\n");
    CKDPrivate(mkey,ekey,h,44);
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){ printf("%02x",ekey[i]);} printf("\n");


    return 0;
}

void GenerateMKey(unsigned char *s, unsigned char *m)
{

    char key[]="Bitcoin seed";

    HMAC(EVP_sha512(),key,strlen(key),s,64,m,0);

}


void CKDPrivate(unsigned char *m, unsigned char *e, unsigned char *x, int i)
{
    
    unsigned char c[32],d[37];
    d[0]=0;
    memcpy(d+1,m,32);
    x[3]=i;
    memcpy(d+33,x,4);
    //d[37]='\0';
    memcpy(c,m+32,32);
    HMAC(EVP_sha512(),c,32,d,64,e,0);
    
}
```

and here is the Valgrind report of the errors

```
@system:~$ valgrind --leak-check=full -v --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes CodeLite/build-Debug/bin/teset3
==187198== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==187198== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==187198== Using Valgrind-3.16.1-36d6727e1d-20200622X and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==187198== Command: CodeLite/build-Debug/bin/teset3
==187198== 
--187198-- Valgrind options:
--187198--    --leak-check=full
--187198--    -v
--187198--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--187198--    --track-origins=yes
--187198-- Contents of /proc/version:
--187198--   Linux version 5.9.0-5-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-1) 10.2.1 20201207, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.1) #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1 (2020-12-17)
--187198-- 
--187198-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-rdtscp-sse3-ssse3
--187198-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--187198-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind
--187198-- Reading syms from /home/soufiane/CodeLite/build-Debug/bin/teset3
--187198-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
--187198--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/8c/8fb7a300a76834b3b719afc53d1201e5aa0af3.debug ..
--187198--   .. build-id is valid
--187198-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--187198--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/54/299c4aec0e5e5f3d7b8135341351d0e1dbfc64.debug ..
--187198--   .. build-id is valid
--187198--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--187198-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--187198-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/default.supp
==187198== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-187198-by-soufiane-on-???
==187198== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-187198-by-soufiane-on-???
==187198== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-187198-by-soufiane-on-???
==187198== 
==187198== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==187198== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==187198== or are doing some strange experiment):
==187198==   /usr/bin/vgdb --pid=187198 ...command...
==187198== 
==187198== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==187198==   /path/to/gdb CodeLite/build-Debug/bin/teset3
==187198== and then give GDB the following command
==187198==   target remote | /usr/bin/vgdb --pid=187198
==187198== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==187198== 
--187198-- REDIR: 0x401f820 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x580ca5f2 (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x401f600 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x580ca60c (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_index)
--187198-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--187198--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/f2/7641e081d3c37b410d7f31da4e2bf21040f356.debug ..
--187198--   .. build-id is valid
--187198-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--187198--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/25/7cdcdf80e04f91ca9e3b185ee3b52995e89946.debug ..
--187198--   .. build-id is valid
==187198== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--187198--     old: 0x0401f820 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x580ca5f2 vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen
--187198--     new: 0x0401f820 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x0483bda0 strlen
--187198-- REDIR: 0x401c040 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x483cc90 (strcmp)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x401fd60 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4840740 (mempcpy)
--187198-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
--187198--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--187198-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
--187198--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/11/79082c082db1c6e5578c4bda11061283b55ea1.debug ..
--187198--   .. build-id is valid
--187198-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
--187198--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/96/9e918a70cfb70b5b16ef417c282ab5b3bb0bc3.debug ..
--187198--   .. build-id is valid
--187198-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
--187198--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/35/652c7fe24301abe3b020ee8f7a7921c6d10e1b.debug ..
--187198--   .. build-id is valid
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8e40 (libc.so.6:memmove) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf81f0 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf9160 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf7b10 (libc.so.6:strcat) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8250 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bfa4f0 (libc.so.6:rawmemchr) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c126b0 (libc.so.6:wmemchr) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c12250 (libc.so.6:wcscmp) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8fa0 (libc.so.6:mempcpy) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8dd0 (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8190 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf7bc0 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8f00 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c12210 (libc.so.6:wcschr) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf80f0 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf7c90 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf91b0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf7c30 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf9300 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c138b0 (libc.so.6:wcsnlen) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c12290 (libc.so.6:wcscpy) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8290 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf7b70 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf80b0 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bfe850 (libc.so.6:memrchr) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf9200 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp_l) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8d90 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c12330 (libc.so.6:wcslen) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8530 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf9100 (libc.so.6:stpncpy) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf90a0 (libc.so.6:stpcpy) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bfa530 (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf9250 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp_l) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c75510 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_chk) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf8cc0 (libc.so.6:strstr) redirected to 0x482e1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c074d0 (libc.so.6:__strrchr_sse2) redirected to 0x483b7f0 (__strrchr_sse2)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c077c0 (libc.so.6:__strlen_sse2) redirected to 0x483bce0 (__strlen_sse2)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf4090 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4838710 (malloc)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c11a10 (libc.so.6:__memset_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x483f650 (memset)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c115f0 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_chk_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4840820 (__memcpy_chk)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c11600 (libc.so.6:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x483cda0 (memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4bf46c0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4839940 (free)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c072c0 (libc.so.6:__strchrnul_sse2) redirected to 0x48402b0 (strchrnul)
--187198-- REDIR: 0x4c115e0 (libc.so.6:__mempcpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x48403c0 (mempcpy)
f79bb0d317b310b261a55a8ab393b4c8a1aba6fa4d08aef379caba502d5d67f9
==187198== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==187198==    at 0x4BBAE3A: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:180)
==187198==    by 0x4BD4857: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
==187198== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==187198==    at 0x4BBAE4C: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:180)
==187198==    by 0x4BD4857: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
==187198== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==187198==    at 0x4BD5600: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
==187198== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==187198==    at 0x4BD49CE: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
8d0e28426b8fb0d774033f6c1cd3c5d597bb49cd03c3cf777d62f6feb9213cd0
==187198== 
==187198== HEAP SUMMARY:
==187198==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==187198==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 2,720 bytes allocated
==187198== 
==187198== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==187198== 
==187198== ERROR SUMMARY: 186 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==187198== 
==187198== 32 errors in context 1 of 4:
==187198== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==187198==    at 0x4BD49CE: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
==187198== 
==187198== 32 errors in context 2 of 4:
==187198== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==187198==    at 0x4BD5600: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
==187198== 
==187198== 61 errors in context 3 of 4:
==187198== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==187198==    at 0x4BBAE4C: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:180)
==187198==    by 0x4BD4857: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
==187198== 
==187198== 61 errors in context 4 of 4:
==187198== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==187198==    at 0x4BBAE3A: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:180)
==187198==    by 0x4BD4857: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==187198==    by 0x4BC0D3A: printf (printf.c:33)
==187198==    by 0x1092C4: main (main.c:40)
==187198==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==187198==    at 0x109353: CKDPrivate (main.c:57)
==187198== 
==187198== ERROR SUMMARY: 186 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

the expected result is to be

```
56bd579906395c55b7e1707cebbfb96eccd5ecc6dccece47f79bcf255cd6ca9e
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would probably be more readable to use NULL instead of 0 as the last parameter of HMAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear exactly what you want to do BUT:

```
unsigned char c[32],d[37];
```

`d` here is 37 bytes, but you tell HMAC that it is 64 bytes long.

```
HMAC(EVP_sha512(),c,32,d,64,e,0);
```

considering that you define `c` and `d` inside this method, you could:

```
HMAC(EVP_sha512(),c,sizeof(c),d,sizeof(d),e,NULL);
```

(the last parameter of HMAC is an `unsigned int *md_len`... I think it is more readable to use `NULL`)

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't even think that I may be misunderstanding and confusing the paramaters orders of the HMAC function which therefor leads to take partial memeory and reset was arbitory ... I was thinking the 64 is the paramater of the output lol I didn't even image that the error it is because I misused the HMAC function paramaters, thanks so much that solved the problem